# How to delete timer jobs on a site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I am deleting features with powershell script but timer jobs of those features did not get deleted.

It will also be fine if I can delete timer jobs run on a site collection.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

```
$jobToDelete = Get-SPTimerJob | ? { $_.name -eq "sitename" }
$jobToDelete.Delete()
```

sitename=Name of your site

Also you can create filters for getting specific Timer jobs

**Example**

```
$jobToDelete = Get-SPTimerJob –WebApplication “http://test.intranet.local” | Where-Object {$_.name –like “*health*” }
 $jobToDelete.Delete()
```

[Delete Timer Jobs](http://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2011/06/02/how-to-delete-sharepoint-timer-job-using-powershell/)

Comment: what if i have 2 sites with same name in 2 different site collections

Comment: Please see my updated comment

Answer (score 0):

When developing custom sharepoint timer jobs sometimes you want to delete junk jobs created by deployment attempts .
Warning !!! DO NOT DELETE ANY TIMER JOB UNLESS BE SURE
Searching listing and find timer job to delete.We need an id.

```
Get-SPTimerJob | where { $_.name -like “*<your search criteria>*” } |ft id,name
```

Set job to a variable

```
$job = Get-SPTimerJob -id <GUID>
```

And delete it.

```
$job.Delete()
```